# Building a Data analytics website with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, django

I need help with someone giving me advice on how do I go about building a data analytics website with data from PostgreSQL. I research on Django framework to help build a data analytics website but there seems to be a lack of information to help me with it. Can someone tell me how do I go about it? I need to build a website which user and filter out the data, Something like Tableau which is customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Django isn't oriented toward analytics.  Look at [R Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) instead.